# What is the newest linux kernel on EC2?

Tags: linux, amazon-ec2, linux-kernel

What is the newest linux kernel on ec2? I want to make some tests on the newest kernel which I can find on EC2.

Do you know what is the newest linux kernel on EC2, and where can I find it?

Answer (score 2):

Currently it is 3.2.30 in the [2012.09 version](http://aws.amazon.com/amazon-linux-ami/2012.09-packages/) of Amazons Linux ami

Check out this page
http://aws.amazon.com/en/amazon-linux-ami/

If you launch a new instance this is the default ami used for the specific instance type.

After the machine has booted run a

```
sudo yum upgrade --assumeyes && sudo init 6
```

To ensure you got the latest patches

**Edit:**

Current update brings the 3.2 kernel at version 3.2.34 rev 55

```
===================================================================================
 Package              Arch        Version                 Repository          Size
===================================================================================
Installing:
 kernel               x86_64      3.2.34-55.46.amzn1      amzn-updates       9.1 M
```

Comment: And default kernels seems 2.6 for Red Hat 6.3 and 3.2 for Ubuntu 12.04

Comment: Yes, kernel is a package. The kernel you can choose at instance build time is just used for the bootloader when we talk about the amazon linux ami